# Missing Cross-platform template on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

i'm after install updates on visual studio 2017 and create successful my first app with xamarin.forms and cross platform, when i want to create another app i can't find cross-platform template on new project dialog.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and managed to do it
The Visual Studio Installer will open
Under the word Visual Studio Community 2017 there is a word called "More" Click on it to enlarge the word "Repair" Click on it to start downloading After it is finished Press Restart the program and open the program